# Why PBS is called Big Bird as its byname?

Tags: etymology, figures-of-speech

I found “*Big Bird*” being used as the byname of public broad services in the article titled,“The Red and Blue Fantasies behind the Big Bird War” appearing in Time magazine’s October 9 issue which begins with the following sentence:

> "There is a reason conservative’s dream of cutting funding for Big
>   Bird, but it has nothing to do with Sesame Street. Behind the big
>   yellow fowl is a fantasy: the idea that the federal budget can be
>   balanced by doing away with wasteful ephemera that no one really
>   needs. “I like PBS. I love Big Bird. I actually like you too,” Romney
>   said at the first debate to Jim Lehrer, the moderator. “But I’m not
>   gonna keep on spending money on things to borrow money from China to
>   pay for it.”

From the context of the above sentence, I surmise that Big Bird appearing in the popular children’s TV show, “Sesame Street” became the nickname of PBS. 
If I am right, I wonder why just one of 1,000 Sesame Street characters comes to represent for PBS.

Why PBS is called "Big Bird"? The article says “There is a reason conservative’s dream of cutting funding for Big Bird, but *it has nothing to do with Sesame Street.”*

Why don’t you say simply “PBS,” which I think is short enough word that doesn’t need to take a bother of inventing an alias?

Comment: Big Bird here is not a nickname for PBS but a [*metonym*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy).

Comment: @StoeyB.I corrected ‘nickname’ as ‘alias.’ I’m not sure if it agrees with ‘metonym’ you suggested, the word I didn’t know.

Comment: @StoneyB: I don't think it even acts as a metonym, it is simply literally Big Bird (but by implication also Sesame Street and then also PBS), that is, not as a stand in representative for all of PBS.

Answer (score 8):

"Big Bird" is not really a nickname for PBS, but Sesame Street is such an iconic show for the PBS network that to say one almost immediately brings the other to mind.  As StoneyB said in a comment, this is an example of a [metonym](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) (though to be honest I'd never heard the phrase before StoneyB mentioned it).

Why didn't they just say "cut funding for PBS"?   I'd speculate that it was a creative choice.  Saying that you're cutting funding for *Big Bird* (or Elmo, or any other well-loved TV character) makes it sound more personal and thus more dramatic than just saying you're going to cut funding for a network.

As for why "Big Bird" and not one of the other characters?  In Romney's generation, Big Bird was *the* iconic Sesame Street character, so that's probably why that one sprang to mind, but I think you could substitute any other prominent character and achieve the same effect.

Comment: In a political environment, Romney may have also been making a preemptive attempt to deflect criticism that his proposed cuts could hurt children. It's one thing to declare, "I want to cut the _McLehrer News Hour;_" That's likely to elicit a yawn – just like the _McLehrer News Hour_. But when you mention cutting _Sesame Street_ – the show credited with teaching an entire generation the alphabet – well, them's are fighting words.

Answer (score 5):

*Big Bird* was specifically referenced by Mitt Romney in a [statement](http://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/decision2012/mitt-romney-on-spending-cuts-i-like-pbs-i-love-big-bird/2012/10/03/bb0e06e0-0dc7-11e2-a310-2363842b7057_video.html) during the debate last week in which he said he would eliminate federal funding of PBS.

> I'm going to stop the subsidy to PBS. I like PBS. I love Big Bird.

In many ways, Big Bird, and the show in which he/she/it appears, *Sesame Street*, has become iconic for *Public Television*.